Maven Tycho Build Reports Missing Dependency Even Though Matching Artifact Available
I am trying to build an Eclipse RCP application with Tycho. The build says it cannot resolve a certain bundle. But the "missing" dependency at the end of the chain is available from one of the referenced P2 repos. Here is part of the error message (I put blank lines around the key line to make it more visible):
[ERROR]  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.jdt.ui; bundle-version="3.6.0"; visibility:="reexport"
[ERROR]    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.jdt.ui; bundle-version="3.8.2.v20130107-165834"; singleton:="true"
[ERROR]       org.eclipse.jdt.ui [21]
[ERROR]         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.compare; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
[ERROR]           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.compare; bundle-version="3.5.301.v20130125-135424"; singleton:="true"
[ERROR]              org.eclipse.compare [48]
[ERROR]                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="[3.3.0,4.0.0)"
[ERROR]                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="3.8.2.v20121106-170106"; singleton:="true"
[ERROR]                     org.eclipse.ui.ide [11]
[ERROR]                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
[ERROR]                         -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.104.0.v20121024-145224"; singleton:="true"
[ERROR]                            org.eclipse.ui [8]
[ERROR]                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="[3.103.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
[ERROR]                                -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="3.104.0.v20130204-164612"; singleton:="true"
[ERROR]                                   org.eclipse.ui.workbench [100]
[ERROR]                                     Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt
[ERROR]                                       -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt"; bundle-version="0.10.3.v20130124-133900"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt,org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,org.eclipse.ui.workbench"
[ERROR]                                          org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt [82]

[ERROR]                                            Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.databinding; bundle-version="[1.2.0,2.0.0)"

[ERROR]                                     Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.renderers.swt
[ERROR]                                       -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.renderers.swt; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt"; bundle-version="0.10.3.v20130124-170312"; version="0.0.0"; x-internal:="true"
[ERROR]                                          org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt [81]
[ERROR]                                            Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt; bundle-version="0.9.0"
[ERROR]                                              -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt; bundle-version="0.10.3.v20130124-133900"; singleton:="true"
[ERROR]                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="[3.7.0,4.0.0)"

Apparently, Tycho cannot satisfy the constraint Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.databinding; bundle-version="[1.2.0,2.0.0).
But one of the repos in my project's POM is https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.8:
    <repositories>
    ...
        <repository>
            <id>eclipse38</id>
            <layout>p2</layout>
            <url>http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.8/</url>
        </repository>
    ...
    </repositories>

I looked in there and, in one of the subfolders (https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.8/R-3.8.2-201301310800/plugins/), there is an artifact org.eclipse.core.databinding_1.4.1.v20120521-2332.jar. Why is this not getting used? A few of the other deps, for example org.eclipse.jdt.ui_3.8.2.v20130107-165834, are in that same repo, I imagine they must have come from there. The version of org.eclipse.core.databinding does match the specifier, does it not? What else could be going wrong here?
I am using Java 17, Maven 3.9.2, and Tycho 3.0.5 on Windows 11.
Bonus question: the second-last line in my error message points to a bundle:
-> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt; bundle-version="0.10.3.v20130124-133900"; singleton:="true"

but there is no explanation of which constraint of org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt could not be satisfied. Am I correct in inferring that this is a reference to how org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt already failed to resolve earlier on?

org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt is an Eclipse 4.x plugin that looks out of place when you seem to be using Eclipse 3.8

Have you considered using Maven 3.9.9 and Tycho 4.0.9, the current versions?

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.8/ (which is 12 years and 31 releases behind and which should be better start with https instead of http) does not contain those bundles/plugins and packages starting with org.eclipse.e4 that are mentioned in the error message. Better stick to one recent release one instead of mixing stuff from different releases.

Whatever age release you use you must stick to using repos for just one release. It looks like you may be using stuff from 3.8 and 4.2 here which is probably not going to work.

Okay, thanks, I'll try and find out which is the correct Eclipse version that my code is based on and remove all conflicting repos.
But can I get an answer on the original question? It's complaining that it can't find a particular artifact even though that artifact is in one of the repos, which seems a legitimate issue to me. Maybe it will go away once I fix the conflicting repos, but I'd rather find out what specifically is wrong here in order to better understand the whole process.

The error message seems to be wrong. In contrast what the error message says, http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.8/ contains the OSGi bundle org.eclipse.core.databinding in version 1.4.1.v20120521-2332 and 1.4.1.v20120912-135020. You might use the Repository Explorer view which is part of Oomph Targlets for such analyses. Which error message will be shown with Tycho 4.0.9?

I changed the Eclipse version to 4.26, added a target definition, and managed to make some more progress. But now I'm getting the same problem, except this time it's that a module supposedly can't find org.apache.logging.log4j.core:2.17.1, even though it is present at https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/simrel-orbit/2023-09/ (which I have added as a Maven repo for Tycho).
I switched to Tycho 4.0.9, and it produces the exact same error, looks like the bug is still there in that version. Do you know which component has the bug? Is it Tycho itself or something else, like Equinox?

Without a minimal reproducible example, it doesn't look like anything. It could be also a misleading error message for something you did wrong.

Yeah, that makes sense. I thought it might be a known issue that someone can just say "yup, it's issue #12345" without further investigation. A MRE is kind of infeasible in this project. I just hacked around it by adding org.apache.logging.log4j.core as a Maven dependency to my target definition. I might remove all these Maven repos from the POM and put everything in the target definition instead, if Tycho's way of resolving target platform artifacts from Maven repos is buggy.

Tycho works fine for me and I also haven't heard of such an issue from others. Tycho is an active project that is used by many Eclipse projects. If it would be a bug, then it must be a very special case, otherwise it would have been noticed and fixed long ago.
